# Drupal Ubercart: multi-currency?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

what's the safest way to integrate multi-currency support to Ubercart ?

I found this module: http://drupal.org/project/multicurrency
but it is still under development and it says it requires custom installation procedure to be installed.

Is this the main way to do it ? Or am I missing something ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved with this great tutorial:

http://vintagedigital.net/content/how-add-multicurrency-support-ubercart

Comment: Patrick - do you have a link to your website that uses the multicurrency support so I can see a live example?