# Mulitcurrency for Ubercart 3 (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, translation, currency, ubercart

Does any solutions for Ubercart 3 (drupal 7) exist (like  [Drupal Ubercart: multi-currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195279/drupal-ubercart-multi-currency) ) or tips for better realisation of such thing?

Comment: Been there my friend, I'm afraid there's absolutely nothing out there at the moment. Closest you'll get is performing a custom port of the [Multi-currency Support for Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/multicurrency) module to Drupal 7

Comment: Seems so. Only solution i make - is hack uc_store.module file to give something like multicurrency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend that you hardcode it. You would loose all your changes with next update. Try to check this topic: http://drupal.org/node/1434470#comment-5582812

Answer (score 1):

As one of solutions, i find and use this:

in ubercart/store/uc_store.module add new define, for example

```
define('RUR',0.33);
```

where 0.33 - is difference between default currency and new currency (RUR). *rur/dollar = 0.33*

and in uc_currency_format function add this:

```
  global $language;
  if ($language->language=='ru') {
    $sign = ' RUB'; 
    $thou = ','; 
    $dec = '.';    
    $value = $value / RUR;
    $sign_after = FALSE;
  };
```

And full function:

```
function uc_currency_format($value, $sign = NULL, $thou = NULL, $dec = NULL) {
  if ($value === NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  $output = '';

  $sign_after = variable_get('uc_sign_after_amount', FALSE);
  $prec = variable_get('uc_currency_prec', 2);
  if (is_null($sign)) {
    $sign = variable_get('uc_currency_sign', '$');
  }
  if (is_null($thou)) {
    $thou = variable_get('uc_currency_thou', ',');
  }
  if (is_null($dec)) {
    $dec = variable_get('uc_currency_dec', '.');
  };

  // If the value is significantly less than the minimum precision, zero it.
  if ($prec > 0 && round(abs($value), $prec + 1) < pow(10, -$prec)) {
    $value = 0;
  }

  global $language;
  if ($language->language=='ru') {
    $sign = '$'; 
    $thou = ','; 
    $dec = '.';    
    $value = $value / RUR;
    $sign_after = FALSE;
  };

  // Force the price to a positive value and add a negative sign if necessary.
  if ($value < 0) {
    $value = abs($value);
    $output .= '-';
  }

  // Add the currency sign first if specified.
  if ($sign && !$sign_after) {
    $output .= $sign;
  }

  // Format the number, like 1234.567 => 1,234.57
  $output .= number_format($value, $prec, $dec, $thou);

  // Add the currency sign last if specified.
  if ($sign && $sign_after) {
    $output .= $sign;
  };

  if ($value=='0') {
  $output = t('free'); 
  };
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: 10x for this solution.
Look so simple & clean.
Are there disadvantages using this method?

Comment: disadvantages:
in this example it's core changes.
Also in admin and other parts of Ubercart it's stil default curency of store.